# D3 speed issue with link animation in directed graph

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, svg-animate

I am trying to animate the links on a force layout directed graph using the code below. The links are simple lines and not paths. I initiate the animation with a button press. The style change (in onTick) happens immediately but the problem is that the animation itself takes about 10 seconds to start. Am I doing something wrong? Can I speed up the start of the animation. I have to say that once the animation starts, the animation runs very well.

```
function animLink( d )
{
    this.transition()
        .delay(0)
        .duration(10000)
        .ease( "linear" )
        .attrTween( "stroke-dashoffset", function() {
            var i = d3.interpolateString( "1000", "0" );
            return function(t) { return i(t); };
        } )
    .each( "end", function() { d3.select(this).call(animLink); } );
}

onTick = function(e)
{
    if (buttonPressed)
        link
            .style( "stroke-dasharray", "10,10" )
            .call( animLink );
}
```

You can see a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykshg1uf/2/) here. In the beginning there is a 5 second delay even though I am specifying .delay(0).

The graph in the fiddle is pretty small compared to the 2000 nodes I have in mine.

Comment: I think you need `.each(animLink)` instead of `.call(animLink)`.

Comment: actually that made it worst. All the nodes ended up at (0,0) and the animation did not start at all.

Comment: Ok, could you provide a complete example please? What is `link` and where is `onTick` called?

Comment: Updated question with fiddle.

Comment: Don't call this inside the tick handler, it will create a new transition for each iteration of the force layout http://jsfiddle.net/ykshg1uf/1/

Comment: wow, this is what I was looking for. If you want to turn the comments into an answer, I can accept it. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling the code that starts the animation at every iteration (i.e. `tick` event) of the force layout. That is, you're setting it up over and over again so that it doesn't actually have a chance to run because new transitions cancel old ones.

When it actually runs it's because the force layout has settled down and there are no more `tick` events. Solution: call the code outside the `tick` event handler. Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ykshg1uf/1/).